# Archived Apple Messages - How to print or reactivate

Tags: messages, printing, ichat, archive

Is there a way to print or reactivate text messages that have been archived? I can view the archived messages just fine in the ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iChat/Data/Library/Messages directory.

Answer (score 1):

Double-clicking any of those archived messages will reopen that conversation in Messages app.

If you Search in Archive for the caller name [or number if there's no name] then open the most recent archive, that ought to import the entire conversation. If in doubt, bulk-select all the relevant archive files,  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>    <kbd>O</kbd>  will open them all & you can test the newest against the earlier ones. Empirically it does seem to work, but I've only tried it with a couple of test cases, & not any of my 'major' conversations.

Caveat…
Whether the conversation will open correctly in the main Messages window depends on whether you had Prefs > "Save History when conversations are closed" checked *at the time you closed that conversation*.
Without that checked, you can open it in a separate window, but I can find no way to re-merge it to the main window.
If it is checked, it correctly opens in the main window too.