# How do I automatically save messages on my Mac, even after deleting the conversation

Tags: macos, messages

I tend to delete my conversations from Messages to keep it neat, but some messages I don't actually want to be gone forever. How can I have my messages save somewhere in a folder automatically even after I delete them from the Messages app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All messages are saved in ~/Library/Messages so you can create a backup by simply using a cronjob to `cp` them over to your archive folder.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question you asked.

Comment: @Tetsujin How do you figure?

Comment: 'how to automatically save'… they're already saved, though the actual linked convos are destroyed if you don't save history - but there was no mention of backing them up… which you could do the same as any other backup.

Answer (score 0):

It's 'all or nothing' you can't be selective about which to save [unless you juggle this parameter before each time you close a conversation, which might work] but in Messages prefs, check "Save history when conversations are closed"

[image]

Comment: I bet there's a way to customize that parameter so that it doesn't restore the history in the conversation. I wonder if that's possible. Maybe a Stack Overflow question?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. If that box is unchecked, the message history is wiped when you close a conversation.Not the messages themselves, just the history of how they all fit together. if it's checked, then next time a conversation is re-opened, the history is restored to that conversation in Messages. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212294/archived-apple-messages-how-to-print-or-reactivate/212316#212316

Comment: I figured a solution out. Just use a cronjob with a recursive copy to move everything from the messages folder to an archive.